# "With" "condition" or "state" which is correct to describe simultaneous situations?

Tags: conditionals

> 1. Press this button with meals (being) put in the microwave.
> 2. Press this button on (the) condition that meals are put in the microwave.
> 3. Press this button in a state where meals are put in the microwave.

I created these sentences to describe simply "Press this button after meals are put in the microwave", but I want to rewrite this more technically such that the button should be pressed while the meals are kept in the microwave.

It seems to me that the first sentence may be most sophisticated, but I am not sure if it is grammatically correct. Could you advise me which of the three sentences is the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your sentences really mean what you want them to, with the possible exception of #2. All of them are unnecessarily wordy to the extent that they are difficult to even understand. Good writing does not have to use fancy grammatical constructs.

I would word it like this:

> Press this button once the meals have been put in the microwave.

The meaning is clear: You should 1) put the meals in the microwave and 2) press the button.

...or do you mean that the button should *continue being pressed* while the meals are in the microwave, as a dead-man's switch or something like that? (You almost seem to say this when you say "the button should be pressed while the meals are kept in the microwave.") In that case:

> Hold this button down while the meals are in the microwave.

"Hold down" means you should press the button and not let your finger up, while simply "Press" usually means "press and release."